# json_decode in PHP with multiple of the same names but different values

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to decode a json data set with many entires that have the same names but are paired with multiple different values.

Example:

```
{"id":"XXX",
"price":"XXX",
"size":"XXX",
"id":"YYY",
"price":"YYY",
"size":"YYY"}
```

I have no problem building an array when there is only one value for each name by doing this:

```
$array = json_decode($array4,true);
```

PHP array:

```
  array(3) { 
["id"]=> string(3) "XXX" 
["price"]=> string(3) "XXX" 
["size"]=> string(3) "XXX" 
}
```

but when I try to use the whole file which contents ~4000 different values with paired between ~4 names I get a response of NULL when I want the json_decode to be something like:

```
   array(3) { 
["id"]=> string(3) ("XXX","YYY") 
["price"]=> string(3) ("XXX","YYY") 
["size"]=> string(3) ("XXX","YYY") 
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The JSON itself with duplicate keys is not valid.  Do you have any control over how the JSON is built?

Comment: You are correct. I posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Update: I needed to built the json input correctly.
Like below:

```
{"data":[
{"id":"XXX","price":"XXX","size":"XXX"},
{"id":"YYY","price":"YYY","size":"YYY"}]
}
```

Then json_decode works great.